# Tensorflow hub tags and exporting

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-hub

I am very confused how tags are supposed to work in hub and how do i use them when exporting. How can I train on the train part of my graph and export the serving one?

I have the following code:

```
def user_module_fn(foo, bar):
    x = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, shape[-1, 32], name='name')
    y = something(x)
    hub.add_signature(name='my_name', input={"x": x}, output={"default", y})

module_spec = hub.create_module_spec(module_spec_fn, tags_and_args=[
   (set(), {"foo": foo, "bar": bar}),
   ({"train"}, {"foo": foo, "bar": baz})
 ])

m = hub.Module(module_spec, name="my_name", trainable=True, tags={"train"})

hub.register_for_export(m, "my_name")
```

My question is the following: since I am instantiating the module `m` to with `tags={'train'}`, I think I am using the right one for training. Does this imply that I am *only* exporting the one tagged with `train`? How do I use the `train` for training and `set()` (so default) for serving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the best (i.e., simplest) case, your module doesn't need any tags at all, namely when one and the same piece of TensorFlow graph fits all intended uses of the module. For that, just leave `tags` or `tags_and_args` unset to get the default (an empty set of tags).

Tags are needed if the same module needs more than one version of its graph, say, a training version that applies dropout in training mode, and an inference version that makes dropout a no-op. You'll typically see code like

```
def module_fn(training):
  inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 50])
  layer1 = tf.layers.fully_connected(inputs, 200)
  layer1 = tf.layers.dropout(layer1, rate=0.5, training=training)
  layer2 = tf.layers.fully_connected(layer1, 100)
  outputs = dict(default=layer2)
  hub.add_signature(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

...

tags_and_args = [(set(), {"training": False}),
                 ({"train"}, {"training": True})]
module_spec = hub.create_module_spec(module_fn, tags_and_args)
```

Creating the module spec runs module_fn for *all* the provided argument dicts, and stores *all* the graphs built them behind the scenes. When you make a module from that spec and then export it, it will contain all the graph versions that were created, tagged with the respective sets of strings.

The `tags=...` argument to `m = hub.Module(...)` merely controls which of the different graph versions gets used in the current graph, say, when `m` called (i.e., applied to inputs). It does not constrain what `m.export(...)` writes out.

Comment: thanks, this is very useful. I am exactly in the dropout case, where i have a train vs non train case.